# What is the best way to be sure that the detected object is a vehicle?

Tags: opencv, emgucv, motion-detection, background-subtraction

I'm working on a project in which I need to detect moving vehicles. I'm using background subtraction method to extract them and it works pretty good. After applying some morphological transforms, I am able to detect moving vehicles (you can see the output in the rightmost image).

How can I be sure that the moving object is a vehicle and not a non-vehicle moving object?

Training, pattern recognition, etc., I'm looking for the best solution with the lowest possible computational cost for a real-time system.

[detected moving vehicles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygjgo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how much effort you are able to give.  I believe that a small Convolutional Neural Network could do this job amazingly.  One simpler way is to  take several examples of cars and use histograms or SIFT to define features most common to cars in your samples.

Comment: Thanks Fred! I tried HOG, SIFT and SURF but they really decrease the speed, so I decided not to use them for real-time applications. Maybe CNN would be a good solution for my problem. Unfortunately I don't have enough experience in that field :|

Comment: If you know what you want to detect from previous frames, you can use a kalman filter and only try to detect again when it looses the tracked object.

Comment: That's right. But first I want to be sure that the object is a vehicle and then track it. I have some other moving objects like pedestrians in my data-set which I want to skip.